# python how to build a new list from this one

Tags: python

I have a list in the following format:

```
['CASE_1:a','CASE_1:b','CASE_1:c','CASE_1:d',
 'CASE_2:e','CASE_2:f','CASE_2:g','CASE_2:h']
```

I want to create a new list which looks like like this:

```
['CASE_1:a,b,c,d','CASE_2:e,f,g,h']
```

Any idea how to get this done elegantly??

Comment: the second list is not really elegant. a dict key=>list may look better

Comment: Is this homework at all? I know someone added that tag, but it was not the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` by treating case as the key, and appending to the list each letter, where case and the letter are obtained by splitting the elements of your list on `':'` - such as:

```
from collections import defaultdict

case_letters = defaultdict(list)
start = ['CASE_1:a','CASE_1:b','CASE_1:c','CASE_1:d', 'CASE_2:e','CASE_2:f','CASE_2:g','CASE_2:h']
for el in start:
    case, letter = el.split(':')
    case_letters[case].append(letter)
result = sorted('{case}:{letters}'.format(case=key, letters=','.join(values)) for key, values in case_letters.iteritems())
print result
```

As this is homework (**edit: or was!!?**) - I recommend looking at `collections.defaultdict`, `str.split` (and other builtin string methods), at the builtin type `list` and it's methods (such as `append`, `extend`, `sort` etc...), `str.format`, the builtin `sorted` method and generally a `dict` in general. Use the working example here along with the final manual for reference - all these things will come in handy later on - so it's in your best interest to understand them as best you can.

One other thing to consider is that having something like:

```
{1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2: ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']}
```

is a lot more of a useful format and could be used to recreate your desired list afterwards anyway...

Comment: @mgilson I was in two minds about it (as it's been re-tagged), but figured a working answer with points is reasonable enough...

Answer (score 2):

I've deleted my full solution since I realized this is homework, but here's the basic idea:

A dictionary is a better data structure.  I would look at a [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). e.g.

```
yourdict = defaultdict(list)
```

You can iterate through your list ([splitting each element](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on `':'`).  Something like:

```
#only split string once -- resulting in a list of length 2.
case, value = element.split(':',1)
```

Then you can add these to the dict using the list `.append` method:

```
yourdict[case].append(value)
```

Now, you'll have a dict which maps keys (`Case_1`, `Case_2`) to lists (`['a','b','c','d'], [...]`).

If you really need a list, you can [sort](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) the items of the dictionary and join appropriately.

---

**sigh**.  It looks like the homework tag has been removed (here's my original solution):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for elem in yourlist:
   case, value = elem.split(':', 1)
   d[case].append(value)
```

Now you have a dictionary as I described above.  If you really want to get your list back:

```
new_lst = [ case+':'+','.join(values) for case,values in sorted(d.items()) ]
```

Comment: And with just a minor tweak to the `.split()` call, the code could be modified to handle the case of an element which is "Case_23:CSI:Miami".

Comment: @Bob: It means the OP has indicated that we are helping him or her with a school assignment, at which point you help them to figure things out for themselves. Hints, suggestions, not full solutions are expected. The tag is voluntary, you don't just add it to questions without evidence, for example.

Comment: @Bob every question has "tags" associated with it.  You tagged this question as "python" when you submitted it.  Apparently somebody else modified your post and added a "homework" tag.  When I see a "homework" tag, that typically means that I don't want to give a full solution.  However, since the homework tag was apparently in error, I've re-posted my full solution.

Comment: @mgilson and because of that - it's only fair to give you +1 for a Pythonic solution, and hints when it was presumed homework :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: see, thanks; at mgilson: I'm not the author of the post, but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ['CASE_1:a','CASE_1:b','CASE_1:c','CASE_1:d', 'CASE_2:e','CASE_2:f','CASE_2:g','CASE_2:h']

output = {}

for item in data:
    key, value = item.split(':')
    if key not in output:
        output[key] = []
    output[key].append(value)

result = []
for key, values in output.items():
    result.append('%s:%s' % (key, ",".join(values)))


print result
```

outputs

```
['CASE_2:e,f,g,h', 'CASE_1:a,b,c,d']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydict = {}
for item in list:
    key,value = item.split(":")
    if key in mydict:
        mydict[key].append(value)
    else:
        mydict[key] = [value]
[key + ":" + ",".join(value) for key, value in mydict.iteritems()]
```

Not much elegance, to be honest. You know, I'd store your list as a dict, cause it behaves as a dict in fact.

output is `['CASE_2:e,f,g,h', 'CASE_1:a,b,c,d']`